# In hook_form_alter how can I attach libraries on frontend only?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to attach a js file to a form using hook_form_alter() but I don't want to js to be loaded on the administration template.

How can I achieve something like this? With what do I need to replace the `THEME != ADMINTHEME` part in the following code snippet?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (($form_id == 'node_CUSTOM_edit_form' || $form_id == 'node_CUSTOM_form') && THEME !== ADMINTHEME) {
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'MYMODULE/myLib';
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if current page is an admin page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219370/how-to-test-if-current-page-is-an-admin-page)

Comment: Just add an not-operator in front of `\Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute()`. Like `if (!\Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute()) { ... }`.

Comment: (You also need to pay attention to your if-request. I edited your question to wrap the two form ID parts in an extra set of brackets to make sense. You could also use `in_array()` for that.)

Comment: If this is for the public facing theme, why not do it in the theme itself rather than a module?

Comment: Thank you leymannx for your suggestion. I've seen that answer and tried to make it work but it only obliges to one condition or the other (it doesn't work when I check for both my node form && not the admin theme).

Alfred Armstrong - thanks. This solved my issue but did not necessarily answer the question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can get the active theme name using below code in module file.

`$activeTheme = \Drupal::service('theme.manager')->getActiveTheme()->getName()`

and check if `$activeTheme !== 'Your admin theme'`.

**Recommended way:**

In your case as you want to add library specific to theme, it should be added in theme file and not module file.